# PHP hello world

Tags: php

I am working on a project to create a simple PHP application.

For the first step I want to use php to display " Hello world" program on the web server

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "hello world";
        ?>
        <p>
            Here we go
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have uploaded the file and the HTML "Here we go" displays but not the PHP `echo "hello world"`  does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Did you name the file appropriately with the PHP extension (example: `test.php`)? If so, is your web host (or localhost server) PHP-capable?

Comment: what is the name of the file you created?

Comment: view the source of the page in your browser. if you see the raw php code (e.g. the `<?php` and `?>` stuff), then your server is misconfigured and/or you're using the wrong file type and the file is **NOT** being processed as a php script

Comment: I have tried that if I make it test.php nothing displays at all.

Comment: Thanks Marc B this is for a project at University and we have already had issues with file permissions being set wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure PHP is installed on your server? A good test for this would be to use the following:

```
 <?php

      // Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
      phpinfo();
 ?>
```

Save this in a .php file and try and access it via a browser. If PHP is enabled and working correctly you should see a large amount of information about the current state of PHP. This includes information about PHP compilation options and extensions, the PHP version, server information and environment (if compiled as a module), the PHP environment, OS version information, paths, master and local values of configuration options, HTTP headers, and the PHP License.

If you get a blank page, you know that PHP isn't configured at all or correctly on your server.

If you perform this step and you get some output then it would look as though either your file extension is wrong on the file you have to code in above or as Amal suggest you are not actually using a server to begin with.

Comment: It is the University Server I have also tried phpinfo ( was the first thing ) it also just returned a blank page. Thank you a lot for the help I will e-mail our server administrator and ask about this issue.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of some help. As AMAL suggests, if you have your own machine, look into using XAMPP as a development server that way if your Uni Server screws up again you won't fall behind with your work. You can easily port over all of your .php files when you are happy with them :-)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server-side language and you won't be able to load it up in a web browser just like that. You'll have to use a web server, like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for example.

Make sure of these things first:

- that PHP is installed and running on your computer
- that the file extension is `.php`
- that you're accessing the php file with something like `localhost/yourfile.php` and not `file://yourfile.php`
- that the permission for your files is correct (644 or 755 would be enough, I think)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user1955349: If this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the Tick mark.